# Keeping CSS Styles while ExtJS 3 to 4 Migration

Tags: css, extjs, migration, styling

After upgrading our ExtJS 3 application to ExtJS 4 the appearance of some (but not all) components changed. That application uses three CSS files: the original ext-all.css and two own files written many moons ago. These two files seems to be generated and define class-based rules like

```
.x-menu-group-item .x-menu-item-icon {
  background-image: none;
}

.x-menu-plain {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.x-menu .x-date-picker {
  border-color: #AFAFAF;
}
```

To restore appearance of the application, I could

1. Rewrite the own two files from scratch.
2. Keep the files and define new rules for the odd looking components. To do that I have to hand-pick them with Firebug and guess which of the many CSS classes used by the component I have to restyle. That should take days.
3. Style the application with the new theming support which I don't know yet. That should be the last option because it could take too long. Also I don`t see how the existing CSS file can be imported in SASS.

**So, what is the best way to restyle my ExtJS 4 application like the old one?**

Edit: I don`t want to write CSS in the code by applying a "style" argument. The CSS files have to take care of styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, theming is the absolut right way to do this. I managed to restore the most important styles of the application by following this [guide-to-custom-themes-in-extjs-4](http://www.rallydev.com/engblog/2011/10/07/a-guide-to-custom-themes-in-extjs-4/).

Soon I ran into [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158358-4.0.7-Syntax-errors-when-compiling-SASS-themes) bug and solved it with downgrading sass to 3.1.1 like it was mentioned [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?149266-Theming-issue-Line-15-Functions-may-only-be-defined).

To restore most of the design I just had to redefine the following variables in the **my-ext-theme.scss**:

```
$grundblau: #b9d7ff;
$panelrandgrau: #D0D0D0;
$panelgrau: #f1f1f1;

$base-color: $grundblau;

$panel-border-color: $panelrandgrau;
$panel-frame-background-color: $panelgrau;
$panel-header-color: #333333;
```

As you can see, the custom design of the application is actually pretty simple. :)